# Reading different tables from a directory into an array of separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have several CSV files (tables) in a directory (all tables have different schemas) and want to loop over the files and read each table into a separate dataframe.

Is there any way to do this in Python/Pandas - to read the different tables into a dataframe array? How multiple tables (with different schema) be imported into a multiple separate data frames?

Comment: do you want one dataframe or several dataframes?

Comment: Ideally separate dataframes...

Comment: Guys its not really a duplicate since the other q says '# Assemble all of the data files into a single DataFrame & add a year field' - which is not what this question asks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this;

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
os.chdir("E:/") # change this to the directory where your csv files are stored
csv_files = {} # we store the dataframes in a dictionary
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"): 
    csv_files[file] = pd.read_csv(file)

for dataframe in csv_files.values():
    print dataframe
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How does this work exactly? It seems to read a variable into the df and then overwrite it? I am probably not reading it correctly (while looping over the CSV files in the dir).

Comment: I've just removed `df = 'data' + str(i)`. It dint make sense there. Correct. The `df` is being overwritten.

Comment: I think this is a good solution. Would be nicer without the df variable (and the printing). Some explanation of glob.glob would make this excellent :)

Comment: Thanks for this @Richie - I get error 'Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 24 fields in line 6927, saw 26' - how do I overcome this?